# Connect to Redshift via IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

I've got IAM Credentials (access_ky_ID and secret_access_key) and I'd like to connect to a Redshift Cluster.

Is it possible without the user and password couple?

Comment: See: [Using IAM authentication to generate database user credentials - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html)

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, I see the process is way more complex than what I described. I reported my experience that worked for me (probably the client I use does many steps automatically for me). I'll try to read the documentation you reported and update the answer

Answer (score -1):

Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-configure-jdbc-odbc.html

Yes it is. I personally use a JetBrains IDE, so there might be some differences but fundamentally the concepts are gonna be the same.

In the General tab you need to set:

- User: the user name that is going to identify you within the cluster
- URL: `jdbc:redshift:iam://<host>:<port>/<DB>`

In the Advanced tab you need to provide:

- AccessKeyID: access_ky_ID
- AutoCreate: `True`
- DbGroups (optional): the user group of which the new user will be part
- SecretAccessKey: secret_access_key